# Parse list of strings and find max values

Tags: python, max, nested-for-loop

I'm quite new to Python and struggling to get my head round the logic in this for loop. My data has two values, a city and a temp. I would like to write a "for loop" that outputs the maximum temp for each city as follows:

```
PAR 31
LON 23
RIO 36
DUB 44
```

As it is to be used in Hadoop, I can't use any python libraries.

Here is my dataset:

```
['PAR,31',
 'PAR,18',
 'PAR,14',
 'PAR,18',
 'LON,12',
 'LON,13',
 'LON,9',
 'LON,23',
 'LON,5',
 'RIO,36',
 'RIO,33',
 'RIO,21',
 'RIO,25',
 'DUB,44',
 'DUB,42',
 'DUB,38',
 'DUB,34']
```

This is my code:

```
current_city = None
current_max = 0

for line in lines:
    (city, temp) = line.split(',')
   
    temp = int(temp)
    
    if city == current_city:
        if current_max < temp:
            current_max == temp

    current_city = city
            
print(current_city, current_max)
```

This was my output:

```
DUB 0
```

Comment: You result should be a dictionary of `{city: max_temp}`.  Loop through dataset, split string into city and temperature, check if temperature if greater than the one already in dictionary.  Use `dict.setdefault` and/or `dict.get`.

Comment: Thanks. Is dict.setdefault and/or dict.get part of core python? I really have no idea how to do this. I have spent probably over 10 hours on this already and I just don't know how to go about it?

Comment: I'll try this....https://datagy.io/python-get-dictionary-key-with-max-value/#:~:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20get,maximum%20value%20of%20any%20iterable.

Comment: "Is dict.setdefault and/or dict.get part of core python?" — [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dictionary keyed on city names. The associated values should be a list of integers (the temperatures).

Once the dictionary has been constructed you can then iterate over its items to determine the highest value in each list of temperatures,

```
data = ['PAR,31',
        'PAR,18',
        'PAR,14',
        'PAR,18',
        'LON,12',
        'LON,13',
        'LON,9',
        'LON,23',
        'LON,5',
        'RIO,36',
        'RIO,33',
        'RIO,21',
        'RIO,25',
        'DUB,44',
        'DUB,42',
        'DUB,38',
        'DUB,34']
d = {}
for e in data:
    city, temp = e.split(',')
    d.setdefault(city, []).append(temp)
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, max(map(int, v)))
```

**Output:**

```
PAR 31
LON 23
RIO 36
DUB 44
```

Comment: Building lists of temperatures is unnecessary and a bit wasteful

Comment: In what sense is it "wasteful"?

Comment: You keep all the temperatures in a list in memory for no good reason.  First, you waste memory on that list, then you make `min` traverse every list once again.

Comment: I wonder why my solution is faster than yours. I don't use *min*. Take a look here: https://pastebin.com/fiD64Pf4#v3gfMWTZ Results are in the Comments section. Maybe it's because you call *max()* 17 times and I only call it once. Yes, my solution uses more memory but that's invariably a reasonable trade-off for improved performance

Comment: Good point!  Function calls in Python are indeed expensive.  I've modified my solution to compare values directly without calling `max`, and on huge lists it performs a bit better than yours (still without creating a bunch of lists =)

Comment: _"I don't use `min`"_ — sorry, of course I meant `max`

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over your list. Separate your data. Check if the City is already in the dictionary. If so check if the temp is higher as the one saved in the dictionary if that's the case replace the entry in the dictionary.

If the city isn't in the dictionary simply add it into the dictionary.

```py
a = ['PAR,31',
 'PAR,18',
 'PAR,14',
 'PAR,18',
 'LON,12',
 'LON,13',
 'LON,9',
 'LON,23',
 'LON,5',
 'RIO,36',
 'RIO,33',
 'RIO,21',
 'RIO,25',
 'DUB,44',
 'DUB,42',
 'DUB,38',
 'DUB,34']

dict = {}
for entry in a:
    city,temp = entry.split(",")
    if city in dict.keys():
        if dict[city] < int(temp):
            dict[city] = int(temp)
    else:
        dict[city] = int(temp)

print(dict)
```

Output:

```
{'PAR': 31, 'LON': 23, 'RIO': 36, 'DUB': 44}
```

Comment: `city, temp = entry.split(",")`

Comment: Its probably not a good idea to name the dictionary `dict` since that's also the name of the built-in `dict` class. I mean it works here but it could cause weird bugs later on.

Answer (score 0):

Given the answers here are a bit verbose…

```
result = {}

for city, t in (l.split(',') for l in lines):
    t = int(t)
    result[city] = max(result.setdefault(city, t), t)

# you can print result however you like, e.g.:
for c, t in result.items():
    print(f"{c} {t}")
```

If you want to sacrifice a bit of readability for ~30% performance boost, compare values yourself instead of calling `max`:

```
    for city, t in (l.split(',') for l in lines):
        t = int(t)
        old_t = result.setdefault(city, t)
        result[city] = old_t if old_t > t else t
```